# Modelica: access nominal value from equation

Tags: attributes, modelica

Is it possible in Modelica to calculate the value of a Boolean based on the nominal attribute (or min or max) of another variable? Something like:

```
paramter Real a(min=0, max=1, nominal=0.5);
paramter Real b(min=0, max=1, nominal=0.4);
Boolean bBigger;
equation
bBigger = b > a.nominal;
```

I would like to use the Boolean (or directly the expression) in a graphical annotation only.

Comment: I think not... Same for min and max values. I don't know a way to get them with Modelica-only-syntax. In Dymola you can try with the functions in ModelManagement.Structure.AST, but it's not much fun to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare extra parameters if you want to use them in equations such as:

```
parameter Real aNominal = 0.5;
parameter Real a(min=0, max=1, nominal=aNominal);
parameter Real b(min=0, max=1, nominal=0.4);
Boolean bBigger;
equation
bBigger = b > aNominal;
```